# Can anyone explain this behavior in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

This seems like a bug to me, but before I report it to the Typescript repository I thought it would be good to see if there was an explanation for it I am not aware of, here's the [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.1.5#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt3IN4FgBQyyARnFAFzIDOYUoA5gNwEC+BBoksiKAQmcggAPSCAAmVNJhwEipAF6U8hIshiZKNOiCazkLANoBdZvjb4O4aPCTJ+8wSIjjJGLMrlx5AfkogIAG7QpuYEYACeAA58ZPbIALx2AgA+SfKmllw2KAAqEDQyKuro-FD2ABSkUL5qcAA2VBAAlJQAClDoALbAjQA89gB8pkTFpRVVlLQArs1tHd19pUOs7PhwVOEgCGpTW2DA6CBqmGNelWQ18A2zyO1dPRD9XstrG1s7ewdHo7FnE8jTG53BaPJamdabbYwXYIfaHY4lX7yc7VSjETB1CBwEAtW7zB5PMrPQpEYAwZAopok1RQCBgKZQI4eVSeCjIADkCnZABo9ERzPzVkRafTGdTWZROV4eXySF5KAZsAjJVV2fojLyVOZQvgEIcCpAaJQ8gVEsyIe8fkTkVUauj0JjsbjgQTTvIBuLkGSKVUqcyWSKGUzZSz-lL5DKVCyBaodQG6UHPRKOVzNSzPIpkIrlSmyGqWBrZTHtas9SADfkwAAmY2VhLUq32TXmIA).

As you can see in the playground, seemingly identical types throw an error in slightly varied implementations. Is there any explanation for the discrepancy?

Take this interface definition from the playground:

```
interface Test {
  fooBarBaz(bar?: false): Promise<Baz>;
  fooBarBaz(bar: true): Promise<Bar>;
}
```

If I then instantiate an object of type `Test` in the following way:

```
const test: Test = {
  async fooBarBaz(bar?: boolean): Promise<BarBaz> {
    if (bar) {
      return {
        bar: 'baz',
      }
    }

    return {
      bar: 'baz',
      baz: [{ foo: 'bar' }],
    }
  }
}
```

There's an error from the compiler:

```
Type '(bar?: boolean | undefined) => Promise<BarBaz>' is not assignable to type '{ (bar?: false | undefined): Promise<Baz>; (bar: true): Promise<Bar>; }'.
  Type 'Promise<BarBaz>' is not assignable to type 'Promise<Baz>'.
    Type 'BarBaz' is not assignable to type 'Baz'.
      Type 'Bar' is not assignable to type 'Baz'.
        Types of property 'baz' are incompatible.
          Type '{ foo: string; }[]' is not assignable to type 'undefined'.(2322)
```

However, if I declare a function definition like this:

```
async function fooBarBaz(bar?: false): Promise<Baz>;
async function fooBarBaz(bar: true): Promise<Bar>;
async function fooBarBaz(bar?: boolean): Promise<BarBaz> {
  if (bar) {
    return {
      bar: 'baz',
    }
  }

  return {
    bar: 'baz',
    baz: [{ foo: 'bar' }],
  }
}
```

and then instantiate an object of the same type `Test` in the following manner:

```
const test2: Test = {
  fooBarBaz,
}
```

The compiler does not complain at all.

Comment: There's a lot foos and bars there... Can you highlight the important bits? What snippet of code does what you expect and which part does not. Add those snippets to your question in code tags and you may get some better help here.

Comment: There's no way for the compiler to know that a function that returns `A | B` is assignable to an overloaded function signature that sometimes returns `A` and sometimes returns `B` depending on the inputs.  Function statements can declare their overloaded call signatures, but function expressions cannot.

Comment: See [microsoft/TypeScript#38622](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/38622) for some related info (I might get around to writing an answer if I can)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @jcalz, Iook forward to your written out explanation of you get around to it, I'll take a look at the related info when I have time as well.

Comment: @AlexWayne I added some information to the problem to make it more clear.